# Allowing submit encrypted data with no manual access to IE

Tags: java, automation

I am running a test with Selenium and IE.  I need to allow non-encrypted form data to be submitted but I don't have manual access to the IE.  Just through Jenkins.  I do have the same IE on my desk so I can try things at my desk before running on the remote machine. This is what I want to set:

[image]

I can do this with a bunch of robot calls.  Only needs to be done once.  Basically an

```
 ALT t                    -- to select tools
 CTRL-TAB                 -- select security tab
 LEFT                     -- select Internet
 Three TABs and ENTER     -- select Custom Level
 145 DOWN arrows          -- select Enable encrypted send
 BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK        -- select radio button
 three TABs               -- to move to OK
 ENTER                    -- to click OK and close
```

I also repeat with another zone.
As I said, I can test on my machine.  This works fine up to a point.  It successfully gets to Submit non-encrypted form enable, but then when I do ENTER, focus swtches to my selenium window .

The algorithm is fairly simple.  For each key I do a 
robot.keyPress(ch); mywait(1000);robot.keyRelease(ch);mywait(1000).
mywait is just a wait I wrote so I do not have to surround each Thread.sleep() with try/catch.

If there are two keys (like ALT t or CTRL TAB) I do
press key1; wait; press key2; wait; release key 2; wait release key1; wait

For the button click I do

```
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
mywait(500);                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
mywait 500;
```

is this the correct way to select the radio button or is there a better way?  It would be nice if I could just add this to the IE capabilities before I start up IE but I cannot find that option.

My tests kep failing because there was a modal alert open "when you submit unencrypted data people can see what you are doing...".  Various places I tried doing the driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); but I still keep getting the unexpected open alert message.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  This is Java 1.8, IE 11, Selenium on Windows 10 (on my desk is Windows 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found for you after researching a little bit, is using registry to modify that value.

I used Microsoft documentation to check what's the Zone Code and Value for that specific setting.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users

Using CMD reg add you can change it, here is an example for your exact scenario

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /t REG_DWORD /v 1601 /d 0 /f

/t = Type
/v = Name of the registry to change
/d = The value to change to (Enable = 0, Disable = 3)
/f = Force overwrite
```

You can easily run it in Jenkins using bat.

If you need any further help, I'll be glad to help :).

Comment: hmm... let me try that.  Thanks

Comment: How did you ever find that? ;-)

Comment: The most common place for Windows to store all it's settings is the registry, so I thought, might as well check if Internet Explorer saves it there. Googled some to see if Internet Explorer saves it's settings there, and came across Microsoft support website, then I just looked up how to change registry using CMD. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Looks like we can run as that user but not change registry ;-)  However, I found out (finally) how to close the modal and continue (the modal that says people might see what I am doing if I submit unencrypted data) without erroring.  And I think once I click YES it will set it.